# Is HttpContext.Current.Session shared between worker processes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis

In an ASP.NET MVC application is the data in `HttpContext.Current.Session` shared between all worker processes when number of worker processes is greater than 1 in IIS settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Each worker is essentially a different instance of the application, and has it's own `HttpContext.Current`. If you need to share something like session-state between the workers, then you have to set the application up such that each instance will use the same datastore for the session and be able to encrypt/decrypt the same values from that common store. What this essentially boils down to is setting an explicit machine key in your Web.config.